# Using GMap with Dart Angular

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I would like to include google maps in a simple Angular Dart project

The standard way of adding a google map to a web page is to have the following div defined in your html

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

And then include the following somewhere in you code

```
GMap  map = new GMap( querySelector("#map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

All standard stuff but it does not follow the 'angular pattern' where a field on a controller is linked to the html via a ng attribute.

As far as I can see you have to have the html element before creating the GMap object so the element would have to somehow be injected into the controller???

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1):

You can create a component like:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

@Component(selector: 'google-map', template: "<div id='map_canvas'></div>")
class GMapComponent implements ShadowRootAware {
  GMapComponent();

  @override
  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    final mapCanvas = shadowRoot.getElementById('map_canvas');
    GMap  map = new GMap(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried your example and added the GMapComponent via the bind() method to my AppModule class, and left the original html unchanged. When I ran it the Google map did not show up. Nothing interesting was in the logs...help!

Comment: Did you try to set a height on the div ? `<div id='map_canvas' style='height:400px'></div>` ?

Comment: yes, no problem with the size of the div. As far I can see the constructor of GMapComponent is never called - even though it appears in a strange file called  lightning_main_generated_type_factory_maps.dart

Comment: Do you see the `<google-map>` element in your dom tree ? Does it contains a shadow root ?

Comment: When I use chromes 'inspect element' debugger I can only see the original <div id='map_canvas'></div>.

Comment: Added a  <google-map style='height:400px'> element to main html page resulted in a shadow-root. inside the shadow-root is a <div id="map_canvas"> and inside that the GMAP. However the style of the <div> is very odd style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);" - how do I control the style

Comment: A better question, Where is there a simple code example of this?

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin I had the same problem and came to almost the same solution. The funny thing is that by default a Component has set useShadowDom to false. In this case the param in onShadowRoot is an "UnknownElement" but this "UnknownElement" is the Components-HTML-Element. As said - it works but receiving an onShadowRoot-event when using useShadowDom=false is not very intuitive. Should I file a bug or is someone already working on this?

Comment: yep with `useShadowDom: false` `onShadowRoot` is still called but not with a `ShadowRoot` argument. Using `useShadowDom: false` you can replace `shadowRoot.getElementById('map_canvas');` with `document.getElementById('map_canvas');`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually changed it to use the normal component pattern which now works.

```dart
library gmapcomponent;

import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

@Component(selector: 'google-map',
  templateUrl: '/packages/lightning/gmapcomponent.html', 
  cssUrl: '/packages/lightning/gmapcomponent.css',
  publishAs: 'gmap')
class GMapComponent implements ShadowRootAware {

  @override
  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    print( "in onShadowRoot");
    final mapCanvas = shadowRoot.getElementById('map_canvas');

    MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions()
          ..zoom = 4
          ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
          ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
    GMap  map = new GMap(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  }
}
```

The html is then simply

```dart
<div id='map_canvas'></div>
```

and the css is

```dart
#map_canvas { height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Is there a notable difference to Alexandres solution? I can't see it.

Comment: The second solution uses a templateUrl. The first uses a template- or maybe I didn't understand the first solution :) In fact the more I look at it the more I am sure that I have no idea how to use it....

Comment: Using an external template with `templateUrl` or inline `template` shouldn't make any difference here.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, Light has finally dawned on concrete head :)